# IE9+ don't like media-query css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, view, media-queries

Sorry, if this is already solved somewhere in this community, but couldn't find proper solution to this, thus far. I have wrote a html/css for http://www.smartmarine.ee, that works fine in every browser, except IE9+ (no surprise here).

As the css is written in mobile-first approach, then media-query's are used for desktop version, but not implemented by IE9+ (currently no particular need to work in older IE versions). IE9+ seems to read only the first css styling and ignoring everything that comes with media'querys.

I've tried:

- changed measurements in media querys to "px"
- added "meta" tag to html "`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`"
- tried also with "meta" tag "`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE9">`"
- used "`@media all and (min-width:0\0) {}`" in css

When I tested it in IE9 and IE10, I always closed the browser and deleted all the history, to insure that the browser is not stuck with some old data.

I am been stuck with this over a week now and would be thankful to get some solutions to this. It feels to be something simple, that I am missing, but then again ...

I would not copy the html, nor css, here, as it would make this question unnecessarily long, but if you feel I should do it, then let me know.

The site is: http://www.smartmarine.ee

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't seem to recognize any of your backgrounds as well.
I think you need to revise your paths.
I saved the files from different browsers (Chrome and IE), and I've got different folder names with different CSS file names. Also saved one of my websites that work fine and both browsers saved same files, same folders.

Comment: Strange. I have the html and css on root level, where locates also the "imgs" folder for any images. 

IE though reads the core (mobile-first, before media-query's) part of css and finds the images, but seems to refuse to apply the media-query styling rules, that should be applied when the viewport widens.